# heat - heat up, using the phrasal verb, spoken English

Tags: expression-choice

what is the correct one in spoken English?

*she **heats** the soup*

*she **heats up** the soup*

I saw a similar question in the forum but it didn't help me

Comment: The answer is really given in the thread [Meaning of 'up/down' after a verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56135/meaning-of-up-down-after-a-verb/56139#56139). Unlike 'completive up' ('Eat up your food!'), intensifying up ('mess up'), and prototypical directional up ('climb up'), this is a metaphorical usage ("up is an increase in something"): speed up, brighten up, heat up ... (as Thomas says).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that either one is acceptable.  While the active verb "heats" is concise and implies the action of applying heat, the phrase "heats up" indicates a raising of the heat of the soup.

So really either one is fine.