# Reach up / reach for / reach at / reach out / reach down

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I’m trying to describe a character reaching his hands out trying to catch a frog:

_He **reached** his hands **out** to catch the frog…

I wasn’t sure which preposition to use with the phrasal verb.
I looked for some examples in the internet and what I found confused me:

_I saw his hands **reaching up** in the air towards nothing.

_His hand was **reaching for** this woman's bag.

_I was dreaming about hands **reaching at** me.

_He was **reaching** his hand **out** to me.

_You were **reaching** your hand **down** and saying, "Trust me."

Comment: This isn't a phrasal verb.  It's a normal verb with a preposition.  Just like *walk*: you can walk up, walk down, walk around, walk in, walk out, etc.

Comment: Related: [Meaning of up/down after a verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56139/2303) TL;DR: "There really aren't any handy shortcuts. You just have to learn when to use up and down in each phrasal verb you encounter."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To describe a character reaching his hands out trying to catch a frog, one can say:

- He reached **out** his hands **for** the frog.

The prepositions included in OP's question all describe either different directions in which the hands were extended (upwards, downwards, outwards: respectively, *reach up, reach down, reach out*), or the purpose of reaching one's hands (to get or catch something: *reach for*, or to attack somebody: *reach at*).

All of the verbs above can be considered to be multi-word verbs. They may be more or less idiomatic, and therefore less or more transparent, as shown by this table from *English Prepositions Explained* by Seth Lindstromberg:

[image: Degrees of idiomaticity & transparency]

Comment: This is very helpful. I have to consider both the direction and the purpose.